# Popping off screen (from "back stack") represented by a composable to go back to previous screen while using navigation component of Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating a single activity app with Jetpack compose using it's navigation component. I have created composables to represent different screens, and used the navigation component as:

```
@InternalCoroutinesApi
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@Composable
fun ProgressNavigation(themeViewModel: ThemeViewModel?) {

    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Constants.SPLASH
    ) {composable(Constants.SPLASH) {
        ScreenAnimation {
            Splash(navController = navController)
        }
    }
        composable(Constants.HIW) {
            ScreenAnimation {
                LogoPage(false, true, navController = navController) { HowItWorks( navController = navController) }
            }
        }
.
.
.
}
```

Let's say I have 2 screens (composables) "SignUp" and "TnC".
User enters the sign up details in SignUp screen then goes to TnC screen. On coming back to
SignUp screen by pressing a button in TnC screen the details entered earlier in SignUp should remain intact. How do I implement this? If the screens were activities I would do it by popping off the screen from backstack using `onBackPressed`.
How do I do this in my case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `by remember` with `by rememberSaveable` in SingUp composable, then you can use navController.popBackStack() if you are just navigating back or you can use [popUpTo](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop). if you want to navigate back further.

example:

```
navController.popBackStack()
//or
navController.navigate("TnC") {
    popUpTo("SignUp")
}
```

Comment: To make navigation happen I had to replace your code with:

navController.navigate("SignUp") {
    popUpTo("SignUp")
}

Comment: But on navigating back to SignUp page the details entered earlier were lost.

Comment: @SparshDutta Have you tried navController.popBackStack()?

Comment: Yes, that method doesn't seem to exist for compose nav controller

Comment: popUpTo() seems to be accepting a parameter popUpToBuilder() and the default value for "saveState" in it seems to be false.

Comment: Doesn't save details even after setting saveState to true in popUpBuilder()

Comment: Also, popBackStack() does exist. Used it by setting saveStateto true (3rd param) as :                                navController.popBackStack(Constants.TNC, true, true ).

Yet doesn't work

Comment: I figured it out replace by remember with rememberSaveable in SingUp. Then you can use navController.popBackStack() if you are just navigating back and popUpTo if you want to navigate back further.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Please update your answer so that I can mark it as correct answer.